# Laptop brightness keys have a delayed effect or none

Tags: laptop, screen, brightness

My laptop is a Gateway NV52L03H, Amd Radeon HD 7520G using the AMD FGLRX drivers. Most of my laptop's <kbd>Fn</kbd> (function) keys are working properly and as they should. The only one misbehaving are the brightness keys.

When I change the brightness, it either doesn't work, or changes the brightness a few seconds later. I end up having to keep playing with the brightness keys for it to change. I always receive a notification on screen, even though the brightness usually doesn't change.

How can I fix my brightness keys?

Comment: Same problem here. Thinkpad e130

Comment: here is an interesting command: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-power-manager/+bug/847001/comments/10